# Helm3 template error calling include: template: no template "microservice.labels" associated with template "gotpl"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, helm3

I have helm 3 template created using `helm create microservice` command. it has below files.

```
/Chart.yaml
./values.yaml
./.helmignore
./templates/ingress.yaml
./templates/deployment.yaml
./templates/service.yaml
./templates/serviceaccount.yaml
./templates/hpa.yaml
./templates/NOTES.txt
./templates/_helpers.tpl
./templates/tests/test-connection.yaml
```

Updated values file based on my application, when I try to install the helm chat its giving below error message.

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: microservice/templates/ingress.yaml:20:8: executing "microservice/templates/ingress.yaml" at <include "microservice.labels" .>: error calling include: template: no template "microservice.labels" associated with template "gotpl"
helm.go:75: [debug] template: microservice/templates/ingress.yaml:20:8: executing "microservice/templates/ingress.yaml" at <include "microservice.labels" .>: error calling include: template: no template "microservice.labels" associated with template "gotpl"
```

Here is the `ingress.yaml` file.

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "microservice.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if and .Values.ingress.className (not (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion)) }}
  {{- if not (hasKey .Values.ingress.annotations "kubernetes.io/ingress.class") }}
  {{- $_ := set .Values.ingress.annotations "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" .Values.ingress.className}}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.19-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
{{- else if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "microservice.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- if and .Values.ingress.className (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion) }}
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.className }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            {{- if and .pathType (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" $.Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion) }}
            pathType: {{ .pathType }}
            {{- end }}
            backend:
              {{- if semverCompare ">=1.19-0" $.Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion }}
              service:
                name: {{ $fullName }}
                port:
                  number: {{ $svcPort }}
              {{- else }}
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
              {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

How to I added `microservice.labels` template?. Do I need to create `microservice.labels.tlp` file?

Any tips to fix this error.

Thanks
SR

Comment: `/templates/_helpers.tpl` file have the definition of `microservice.labels`. I created a new chart with helm cli and I can see the config in there.

Comment: @Bala  Thanks, I didn't added some details, I copied the ingress.yaml file to, chat created older version helm. this value was missing in `_helpers.tpl` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I copied the `ingress.yaml` file to, chart created older version helm. this value was missing in `_helpers.tpl` file. Now I copied new version of hellpers.tpl file. deployment works now.